# CSS/Javascript Overflow-x with 2 rows

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow, horizontal-scrolling

[VISUAL EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYzYS.png)

Please view the "VISUAL EXAMPLE" link above. I need the **numbered divs** inside the container div to fill left-to-right in the **same order they are numbered**. Then when too many divs come into the container, the horizontal scroll will activate.
Here's what I've tried so far:

Container:

```
.container {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 925px;
  width: auto;
}
```

Inner Divs:

```
.inner-div {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 400px;
    width: 355px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing overflow-x to auto instead of scroll will solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response Envision, it's funny you say that, I was debating whether I should change that width property to a concrete value rather than auto so others wouldn't recommend that change. Because I have read another question where setting a fixed width was the solution. However that does not work here. I set overflow-x to auto like you suggested, and have the width set to something fixed like 1300px and still no luck. The divs refuse to fill vertically first before they start filling to the right, at the moment my screen is one row of the divs with the scrolling enabled.

Comment: @Blawkyy I guess you should update your question to be more clear. I thought your issue was related to horizontal scroll. Please explain what you mean by `The divs refuse to fill vertically first before they start filling to the right, at the moment my screen is one row of the divs with the scrolling enabled.`

Comment: Look at the picture I posted above, I'd like the divs to fill vertically as two rows first before they start to fill right, then when the divs max out their size in the container, the horizontal scroll will be there to account for that. Ultimately, I'd like to have 2 rows of the divs, not 1 row. Right now with the above CSS it will only display as 1 row.